# Image viewer and high ram usage

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am making a simple image viewer in WPF using FreeImage wrapper for .NET (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/)

Here is the code

```
    public static void OpenImage(string path)
    {
        _rawImage = new FreeImageBitmap(path);
        BitmapSource bs = Utils.BitmapToBitmapSource(_rawImage.ToBitmap());
        mainWindow.imageComponent.Source = bs;
        mainWindow.imageComponent.Width = _rawImage.Width;
        mainWindow.imageComponent.Height = _rawImage.Height;

    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32")]
    static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

    public static BitmapSource BitmapToBitmapSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
    {
        IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
        BitmapSource bs = null;
        try
        {
            bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip,
               IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
               System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteObject(ip);
        }

        return bs;
    }
```

The problem is ram spike and overall ram usage when displaying the image. The image I use for testing is a 5000x5000 jpeg. FreeImage reports it takes up 70mb of ram when in memory, which is correct. My app takes about 100mb(~30 for WPF and 70 for image) if I run only this part:

```
_rawImage = new FreeImageBitmap(path);
```

but when the full code is ran memory spikes to about 280mb which is way too much. In production code I can obviously dispose of all unused items but the initial spike is too much. I use IrfanView for image browsing and with same image it takes up a mere 77mb of memory.

I would like some solution(if there is one) to get rid of the spike it takes to load and convert the image into format that wpf Image can display. Maybe further reduce ram usage if possible. I work with big images and it's terrible if it will take 3x memory to load one image. I am rather new to WPF and this stuff overall so there might be something I'm missing.

If there is no possible solution in WPF, maybe something else? I am open for suggestions.

I tried searching but failed to find anything to solve my current problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have no idea what freeimage is, but you don't need any of that in WPF. WPF has it's own mechanisms for everything and does not care about GDI or other crappy dinosaur frameworks. You should remove that and use pure WPF stuff instead.

Comment: I need FreeImage because it supports a lot of image formats like raw, hdr and psd to name a few.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72002/Displaying-Raw-Images-Using-WPF) is an example to load RAW using WPF. that freeimage thing is based in dinosaur GDI stuff, which will not work well in WPF.

Comment: My guess is that you are converting the image to a 32 bit per pixel representation in memory.  5000 * 5000 * 4 bytes = 200 MB.  If IrfanView uses GDI, and the image is on the local hard drive, then it could be taking advantage of using a memory mapped file handle to keep the memory requirements low.

Comment: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/38dfd9a8-17fb-4b12-a513-5ce74208144b/) seems to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: @mbeckish Makes a great point. Loading 5000x5000 at 32bpp and keeping the entire thing in memory will of course use up a lot of memory. There is no way around that. You can, however, limit the amount of memory you're using by showing/storing parts of the image the user can see at the current time.

Comment: @Edgar did you end up using FreeImage or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

```
<Window x:Class="LargeJpeg.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Image x:Name="Image" Stretch="None"/>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();

        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\5x5.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
        bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = (int)Image.ActualWidth;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        bitmap.Freeze();


        Image.Source = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Average memory usage: 130 mb on a 5000 x 5000 jpeg.

Comment: If image doesnot loaded ActualHeight and ActualWidth will be equals to 0. Better to take parent container size.

Comment: Anybody has the answer to why 5000 x 5000 jpeg takes almost 100 MB memory in WPF? I am having the exact problem with my app.